# How to restrict firebase phone number verification SMS to be send to only registered phone numbers?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase phone number verification authentication is triggered by the user from the client-side SDKs on my website I am developing. Is there a way to write code such that the firebase api:
a. sends SMSs to only registered phone numbers (existing registered users) and
b. not send SMSs to unregistered phone numbers (anonymous users)?

This is to prevent data abuse by anonymous users to my website.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way within the Firebase Authentication API to limit what users can authentication through SMS, or any other provider.

The logic here is that in order to know whether a user is authorized, you first have to know who that user us, which already requires them to authenticate.

This does indeed means that a malicious user can make calls through the API with your configuration data. You'd then typically prevent those users from accessing your application by a further check, for example by having the list of approved phone numbers you mention. The difference is that this check happens *after* the authentication step, and not as part of it.

Firebase has abuse prevention methods in place already, so there's usually nothing you need to do beyond calling the API and protecting your backend resources. If you suspect you're seeing abuse on your project, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.